# Obter minutos entre dois horários

Tags: javascript, data, momentjs

```js
var dtChegada  = "16:40";
var dtPartida = "11:20";

var ms = moment(dtChegada,"HH:mm").diff(moment(dtPartida,"HH:mm"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + "h" + moment.utc(ms).format(" mm") +"m";
                  
console.log(">"+d);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira para o senhor resolver, é, converter os horários para segundos e subtrair a diferença. Ex: Pegue os 2 horários, converta-os em segundos, subtraia a diferença, pegue o resultado da diferença e converta-o em minutos.

Veja bem, esse é um problema bastante conhecido, que foi resolvido e documentado e padronizado como *POSIX TIME*

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix

Também existem bibliotecas prontas para fazerem esse trabalho. Uma das minhas favoritas é o MomentJS

https://momentjs.com/

Boa sorte !

Answer (score 0):

Por que não usa [`asMinutes()`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/08-durations/06-minutes/) diretamente no `d`? Bastava usar este método que ele retorna o valor da diferença em minutos já previamente calculada entre, neste caso, `dtChegada` e `dtPartida`.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var dtChegada  = "16:40";
var dtPartida = "11:20";

var ms = moment(dtChegada,"HH:mm").diff(moment(dtPartida,"HH:mm"));
var d = moment.duration(ms); // use neste "d" o asMinutes()
var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + "h" + moment.utc(ms).format(" mm") +"m";
                  
console.log(">"+s);
console.log("Em minutos: " + d.asMinutes())

var dtChegada2  = "19:27";
var dtPartida2 = "06:20";

var ms2 = moment(dtChegada2,"HH:mm").diff(moment(dtPartida2,"HH:mm"));
var d2 = moment.duration(ms2);
var s2 = Math.floor(d2.asHours()) + "h" + moment.utc(ms2).format(" mm") +"m";

console.log(">"+s2);
console.log("Em minutos: " + d2.asMinutes())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function with pure js (without moment)

```
function diffMin(start, end) {
    var diff = 0;
    start = start.split(':');
    end = end.split(':');
    diff = (new Date(null, null, null, start[0], start[1]).getTime() - new Date(null, null, null, end[0], end[1]).getTime());
    diff = Math.abs((diff/1000)/60)
    return diff;
}
var min = diffMin("16:40", "11:20");
console.log(min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar `asHours` e arredondar com `Math.floor`, você pode simplesmente usar `hours` (conforme indicado [na documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/), os *getters* que começam com `as` retornam a duração total, enquanto que suas versões sem `as` retornam os valores já arredondados).

O mesmo vale para os minutos: em vez de usar `moment.utc`, use `minutes`. A formatação ficaria assim:

```
var s = d.hours() + "h " + d.minutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') +"m";
```

E para obter o **total** em minutos, você pode usar `asMinutes`:

```js
var dtChegada  = "16:40";
var dtPartida = "11:20";

var ms = moment(dtChegada, "HH:mm").diff(moment(dtPartida, "HH:mm"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var s = d.hours() + "h " + d.minutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') +"m";

console.log("Formatado: " + s);
console.log("Total em minutos: " + d.asMinutes());
```

```html
    <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Só usei `padStart` nos minutos para que seja mostrado com o zero à esquerda caso o valor seja menor que 10 (pode fazer o mesmo com as horas, se quiser).

---

#### Atenção: não use `moment.utc` neste caso

Vale lembrar que ao usar [`moment.utc`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) você está na verdade criando uma data (e não mais uma duração), que **por coincidência** possui o valor dos minutos igual à quantidade de minutos da duração. Mas de forma geral não se deve misturar as coisas.

Uma data/hora representa um ponto na linha do tempo (uma data é um ponto específico do calendário, um horário é um momento específico do dia). Uma duração é uma quantidade de tempo, sem qualquer relação com calendários ("são duas da tarde" é um horário, um momento específico do dia, já "o filme tem duas horas de duração" é uma duração: uma quantidade de tempo, não diz que horas começa ou termina, só quanto tempo dura).

Por isso que existe o `moment.duration`, já que durações são diferentes de uma data, e você não deve misturar as coisas, mesmo que "funcione".

---

Mas claro que também dá para fazer sem `moment`:

```js
function totalMinutos(horario) {
    const [h, m] = horario.split(':').map(v => parseInt(v));
    return h * 60 + m;
}

var dtChegada  = "16:40";
var dtPartida = "11:20";

// diferença dá o total em minutos
var diff = totalMinutos(dtChegada) - totalMinutos(dtPartida);
console.log(`Total em minutos: ${diff}`);
var h = Math.floor(diff / 60);
var m = diff % 60;
var formatado = `${h}h ${m.toString().padStart(2, "0")}m`;
console.log(`Formatado: ${formatado}`);
```

Lembrando, claro, que estamos assumindo que ambos os horários estão no mesmo dia. Mas se quisesse, por exemplo, das 20:00 de um dia até as 03:00 do dia seguinte, aí as strings teriam que ter as datas também.